# How to make a where clause is optional in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a situation like user will search the records, they will give the conditions in where clause. So they may give conditions or may not. So in this criteria How to make a query.

For example, User may search all records. Some times they may search with date between. So how to make a query the column field of Date is optional.

This is my query

```
select  transactions.storeid as StoreID, MONTH(transactions.Time) Month, 
        transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber,transactionsEntry.Quantity,
        items.ItemLookupCode,items.DepartmentID,items.CategoryID,items.SubDescription1,
        suppliers.SupplierName,suppliers.Code
FROM        [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction] as transactions
RIGHT JOIN  [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry] as transactionsEntry
ON transactions.TransactionNumber=transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber 

INNER JOIN  [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item] as items
ON transactionsEntry.ItemID=items.ID

INNER JOIN  [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Supplier] as suppliers
ON items.SupplierID=suppliers.ID

where 
    YEAR(transactions.Time)=2015 and transactions.TransactionNumber='5526499'  
    and items.ItemLookupCode='806077P0001' and transactions.StoreID='2001'
```

Here, user may search year=2015 or they may not search. So how can i handle this.

Comment: How are you passing in `2015`?

Comment: Tip of today: Never, ever do `RIGHT JOIN`, switch to `LEFT JOIN`. (Most people find RIGHT JOIN way too confusing. `main table left join optional data` is much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `NULL` for the date parameters when you don't to search accroding to year and in `WHERE` clause add an `OR` condition with `@Year` `IS NULL`

```
declare @year INT=2015

select  transactions.storeid as StoreID, MONTH(transactions.Time) Month, 
        transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber,transactionsEntry.Quantity,
        items.ItemLookupCode,items.DepartmentID,items.CategoryID,items.SubDescription1,
        suppliers.SupplierName,suppliers.Code
FROM        [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction] as transactions
RIGHT JOIN  [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry] as transactionsEntry
ON transactions.TransactionNumber=transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber 

INNER JOIN  [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item] as items
ON transactionsEntry.ItemID=items.ID

INNER JOIN  [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Supplier] as suppliers
ON items.SupplierID=suppliers.ID

where 
    (YEAR(transactions.Time)=@year OR ISNULL(@year,'')='')  and transactions.TransactionNumber='5526499'  
    and items.ItemLookupCode='806077P0001' and transactions.StoreID='2001'
```

If the year is not hard coded, pass it to `@year` variable and use in the query.

**Update:**

In case you want to compare it with comma seperated string,declare `@year` as `varchar(100)` like

`declare @year INT=2015` to `declare @year VARCHAR(100)='2014,2015'`

and then change the where condition like:

```
 (CHARINDEX(','+CAST(YEAR(transactions.Time) as VARCHAR(4))+',',',' + @year + ',')>0 
   OR ISNULL(@year,'')='')  
   and transactions.TransactionNumber='5526499'  
   and items.ItemLookupCode='806077P0001' and transactions.StoreID='2001'
```

The above query will check if the year of transactions.Time is present in the @year or not and display the results accordingly.

**Note:** Specify the size of varchar according to your needs, that will result in better performance.

Comment: If it's adhoc query then how do you expect to get the variable `@year`?

Comment: @Jibin Where i have to declare value for @year?

Comment: @Rahul . . . A variable seems like a very reasonable solution to the OP's question.  I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah but not unless the query present in procedural block I believe

Comment: @jibin Suppose if I search like this `YEAR(transactions.Time) in(2012,2013)` how can do with the same logic?

Comment: @mohamedfaisal In that case, @year should be of type `varchar(100)` and you should pass it like `2012,2013`. Then add `CHARINDEX(','+CAST(YEAR(transactions.Time) AS VARCHAR(4))+',',','+@year+',')>0` to the where clause.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Oh my God. Genius. please give me explanation for your code. Its working too. I put like this `where (CHARINDEX(','+CAST(YEAR(transactions.Time) AS VARCHAR(4))+',',','+@year+',')>0 OR ISNULL (@year,'')='')`. Can you explain about this part `VARCHAR(4))+',',','+@year+',')>0`. I don't understand what is really happening

Comment: @mohamedfaisal I have updated my answer, please do check.

Comment: @mohamedfaisal I'm glad it worked for you.. You can mark it as accepted answer and upvote.. So that it will be useful for others who refer this post.